# Mapping Requests to a Nonstandard Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, wsdl, jaxb

I'm writing a bridge between two old application on our network. One has a webservice that takes URL encoded parameters (GET) and returns an XML document. Like this:

http://mytest.com/getData/?format=xml&dateStart=2012-01-01

My question is this - I can use the XSD for the xml returned and marshall it into Java objects (xjc defined).. but is there any way to map the requests/responses to a jax-ws webservice (or similar?) It's not SOAP - so I can't go the WSDL, CXF/JAX-WS route, can I?

I was really hoping for an elegant solution to this without having to code it all from scratch (URL request , returned stream, then marshal). Is there a framework out there that would allow me configure a request? I thought WSDL supported verb="GET" but sadly, I can't seem to get it working with Apache CXF and WSDL2JAVA.

Am I totally off base here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `JAX-RS` may be of use here. Just create XSD schemas and convert them to Java classes, and use a REST client for that site.

You can probably do it with `CXF` too. See [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-HTTPcentricclients).

Comment: hmm that may be the solution - will a rest service take parameterized values in the GET?

Comment: Yes, it should. When you define a REST service, you use @GET annotation to notify, that the server will serve GET requests, and the parameters are supposed to be in the URL. So if you create a client, it should act exactly this way for GET requests.

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm. I ended up using Jersey as the client because it made things very simple

Answer (score 0):

Check out WSGen or you can add ?WSDL to the end of your JAX-WS endpoint to get the generated WSDL.  This way all you have to do is create your JAX-WS annotated classes similar to your JAX-RS ones and the WSDL is generated and it should be able to handle your XJC generated objects with no problems.

http://metro.java.net/guide/ch02.html#create-a-metro-web-services-endpoint

Comment: the endpoint can't change here.. and doesn't have any WSDL - this thing is old and pre-wsdl. It doesn't even support HTTP POST.

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to write a WSDL, it is automatically generated by JAX-WS. But due to your description of the service taking URL encoded parameters and producing XML then it is not SOAP it is REST, which is JAX-RS which Jersey is the standard reference implementation and has a good "Getting Started" guide on jersey.java.net

Comment: You can also define and generate these endpoints for JAX-RS with a WADL similar to generating JAX-WS via WSDL.